# Collapsingtoolbarlayout android

Tags: java, android

Я решил попробовать создать анимированный toolbar ну то есть с картинкой, которая попадает, если прокручивать вниз. Нашел в интернете исходный код, причем два варианта, протестировал что первый, что второй, и что в первом случае что во-втором вся эта штука работает, но дико зависает, а телефон то у меня не древний. Однако в том же вк, все работает на ура. Вот исходные коды.

MainActivity

```
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapterInformation recyclerAdapterInformation;

    CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        //get the bitmap of the drawable image we are using as background
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.header);


        //using palette, change the color of collapsing toolbar layout
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                int mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                int mutedDarkColor = palette.getDarkMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                int vibrantColor = palette.getVibrantColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));

                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(mutedDarkColor);
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(vibrantColor));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: 100500% ваша картинка headеr тяжелая

Comment: как понять тяжелая? размер или качество высокое? или длина?

Comment: Ну фиг его знает я один раз с этой проблемой весь день нервы портил. Картинка оказалась неправильной какой то, в графике не шарю не могу объяснить,  скажу лишь что все дергалось на экране. Картинка весила 80кб. Materialdesign, четкая. Поменял на примитивную, 300кб, вроде больше весит, но проблема исчезла. Раз уж вы код скопипастили то проблема только в этом.